how to remove directories from jupyter config and data search paths
The Jupyter config and data search paths on my machine include the directories below. This is a Windows 10 machine that I do not have admin privileges on as it is managed by an IT department (who can't help me with Jupyter).
$ jupyter --paths
config:
    C:\Users\kerrie\.jupyter
    C:\Users\kerrie\AppData\Roaming\Python\etc\jupyter
    C:\Users\kerrie\anaconda3\etc\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
data:
    C:\Users\kerrie\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
    C:\Users\kerrie\AppData\Roaming\Python\share\jupyter
    C:\Users\kerrie\anaconda3\share\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
runtime:
    C:\Users\kerrie\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime

Here is my version info:
$ jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.20.0
ipykernel        : 6.28.0
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 8.6.0
jupyter_core     : 5.5.0
jupyter_server   : 2.10.0
jupyterlab       : 4.0.11
nbclient         : 0.8.0
nbconvert        : 7.10.0
nbformat         : 5.9.2
notebook         : 7.0.8
qtconsole        : 5.4.2
traitlets        : 5.7.1


I am trying to remove the AppData/Roaming directories from the search paths since they contain all junk kernels or config files that I don't want Jupyter to find. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?
I've searched the Jupyter documentation and only found information for adding additional directories to the config and data search paths (i.e. JUPYTER_CONFIG_PATH, JUPYTER_PATH) but I would like to remove rather than add directories.
